# I Keep Getting These Four Null Pointer Exception and I'm Not Sure Why

Tags: android, json, parsing, nullpointerexception

There is no error in my code and my app runs on my device like it should but with nothing displayed on the screen. This is a strange problem because the Null error was just at one location before when I was test running the app now it has gotten worse without any changing of the code...

This app is a very simple concept that I'm trying to do. I just want to pull an image for a JSON feed and put it in a RecyclerView. Thats all. If you could suggest a more efficient way of doing this that would be great. This has taken me far too long to complete, and I'm on the verge of quitting.

Here is the error I am receiving with the code.

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: zafir.com.motive, PID: 4868
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{zafir.com.motive/zafir.com.motive.Activites.MainActivity}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
 'android.content.Context
 zafir.com.motive.Volley.MyApplication.getApplicationContext()' on a
 null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'android.content.Context
zafir.com.motive.Volley.MyApplication.getApplicationContext()' on a
null object reference
at zafir.com.motive.Volley.MyApplication.getAppContext(MyApplication.java:26)
at zafir.com.motive.Volley.Singleton.<init(Singleton.java:19)
at zafir.com.motive.Volley.Singleton.getsInstance(Singleton.java:44)
at zafir.com.motive.Activites.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6865)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2323)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)                                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)                                                          
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import zafir.com.motive.R;
import zafir.com.motive.RecyclerView.Photo;
import zafir.com.motive.RecyclerView.RecyclerAdapter;
import zafir.com.motive.Volley.Singleton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String API_URL = "LINK";
    private ArrayList<Photo> listPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Sending JSON Volley request
        Singleton singleton = Singleton.getsInstance();
        requestQueue = singleton.getmRequestQueue();

        //Initializing the RecyclerView and it's layout
        RecyclerView recView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this);
        recView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        sendJsonRequest();
    }


    private void sendJsonRequest()
    {
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_URL, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                listPhotos = parseJSONResponse(response);
                recyclerAdapter.setPhotos(listPhotos);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }


    private ArrayList<Photo> parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response)
    {
        if (response == null || response.length() == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                assert response != null;
                JSONObject objectRes = response.getJSONObject("response");
                JSONArray arrayPosts = objectRes.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayPosts.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject object = arrayPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray arrayPhotos = object.getJSONArray("photos");
                    for (int j = 0; j < arrayPhotos.length(); j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject firstPhoto = arrayPhotos.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject originalSize = firstPhoto.optJSONObject("original_size");
                        String url = originalSize.getString("url");

                        Photo photo = new Photo();
                        photo.setImage(url);

                        listPhotos.add(photo);
                    }
                }
            }catch(JSONException e)
            {

            }


        }
        return listPhotos;
    }
}
```

RecyclerAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import zafir.com.motive.R;
import zafir.com.motive.Volley.Singleton;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

    private ArrayList<Photo> listPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
    private Singleton singleton;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context)
    {
        singleton = Singleton.getsInstance();
        imageLoader = singleton.getImageLoader();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setPhotos(ArrayList<Photo> photos)
    {
        this.listPhotos = photos;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, listPhotos.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View recyclerViewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout,parent,false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(recyclerViewLayout);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Photo currentPhoto = listPhotos.get(position);
        String urlThumbnail = currentPhoto.getImage();
        if(urlThumbnail != null)
        {
            imageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate)
                {
                    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return listPhotos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rec_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Singleton

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton sInstance = null;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private Singleton()
    {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext());

        //Managing Image cache.
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache()
        {
            private LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>((int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024/8));

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
            {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                cache.put(url,bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static Singleton getsInstance()
    {
        if(sInstance ==  null)
        {
            sInstance = new Singleton();
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getmRequestQueue()
    {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader()
    {
        return imageLoader;
    }
```

MyApplication

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        sInstance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getsInstance()
    {
        return sInstance;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext()
    {
         return sInstance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Photo(Model class)

```
public class Photo
{
    private String Image;

    //----------Get-and-Set----------

    public String getImage()
    {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image)
    {
        this.Image = image;
    }

    //----------Constructor----------

    public Photo(String urlImage)
    {
        this.Image = urlImage;
    }

    public Photo()
    {

    }

    //----------ToString-------------

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "urlImage" + Image;
    }
}
```

Activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activates.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you specified `MyApplication` as the `name` attribute on the `<application>` element in your manifest?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes I have done so already

Comment: @xZ4FiRx check if they are part of the same layout.